# Read base64 file and convert to jpeg

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, base64, anaconda

I have a folder with a list of filenames in binary format and I would like to convert to all the binary files to jpeg and save it in another folder.

Here is the code that I am using and it works fine when working with a single file

```
import base64

with open('12345-01Image.txt', 'rb') as rf:
    b64 = base64.b64decode(rf.read())

with open('12345.jpeg', 'wb') as wf:
    wf.write(b64)
```

I want to iterate each file in binary format and save it to jpeg.

Really appreciate your help with this!!!

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine. Just using your code adding map function thats all.

```
def bs64_txt_image(text_file: str, extension: str='jpeg'):
    with open(text_file, 'rb') as bin_bs64:
        img_bin = base64.decode(bin_bs64.read())
        with open('.'.join([text_file.split('-')[0], extension]), 'wb') as img:
            img.write(img_bin)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    map(lambda file: bs64_txt_image(file), os.listdir('/path/to/folder'))
```

Comment: Thanks!! Shiv. Pardon my ignorance. i am very much new to python . i tried replacing your code and i got an error.def bs64_txt_image('Users\jijju\source': str, extension: str='jpeg'):
    with open(text_file, 'rb') as bin_bs64:
        img_bin = base64.decode(bin_bs64.read())
        with open('.'.join([text_file.split('-')[0], extension]), 'wb') as img:
            img.write(img_bin)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    map(lambda file: bs64_txt_image(file), os.listdir('/Users/jijju/Destination'))

Comment: can you be explain a bit detail please??

Comment: did you import os ? also are you using **name** and **main** instead of __ name __ and __ main __  ? please make sure

Comment: Thanks Shiv!

<<<import base64
import os
text_file ='12345-01Image.txt'
def bs64_txt_image(text_file: str, extension: str='jpeg'):
    with open(text_file, 'rb') as bin_bs64:
        img_bin = base64.decode(bin_bs64.read())
        with open('.'.join([text_file.split('-')[0], extension]), 'wb') as img:
            img.write(img_bin)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    map(lambda file: bs64_txt_image(file), os.listdir("/Users/jijju/test") >>>


i am passing the src file name to text_file variable and i am saving the jpeg files to test folder. 
correct me if i am wrong??

Comment: Are you on Windows or Linux ? please make sure that the path you are using is compatible to the operating system.

Comment: i am on windows and the initial code i pasted in the beginning worked perfectly fine.

Comment: try r'C:\Users\jijju\test\' as your path, please paste the error message as well